# Set the maximum distance that a turtle can go

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I want to set a maximum distance that a turtle can travel. Using the code below, I want the first turtle who moves distance *x* forward to stop all the turtles:

```
for i in range(130):
    alex.forward(randint(5,10))
    tess.forward(randint(5,10))
    tim.forward(randint(5,10))
    duck.forward(randint(5,10))
    dog.forward(randint(5,10))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need just a bit more infrastructure than you currently have.  To make it easier we'll need to work with individual elements of a list of turtles instead of individual variables for each turtle.  Then we can test if a turtle has crossed the finish line by doing:

```
any(turtle.xcor() > 300 for turtle in turtles)
```

Here's an minimalist, example implementation:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

COLORS = ["red", "green", "blue", "cyan", "magenta"]

for index, color in enumerate(COLORS):
    turtle = Turtle('turtle')
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setposition(-300, -60 + index * 30)

screen = Screen()
turtles = screen.turtles()

while True:
    for turtle in turtles:
            turtle.forward(randint(5, 15))

    if any(turtle.xcor() > 300 for turtle in turtles):
        break

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: It's not possible to stop in some position, even if the radiant it was more than enough to pass the valour?